# how do I align children element centered vertically and horizontally only set up css on child element level

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have one html and css that I want to make sure children elements `svg` and 2 `<p>` elements centered both vertically and horizontally. I have tried `align-items justify-content` on my parent element it works. But it also change the other properties. so is it possible to set up the child element `ONLY` on child element css level

html file

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 
    <p>it should be center</p>
    <p>it should be center on vertical</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css file

```css
// center horizontally. styles on parent
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.box {
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jacobcan/pen/WNpdWMV

Comment: *But it also change the other properties* --> clarfiy this point

Comment: my app is under react so the box only display under if condition. else it should  display the other element `div class='second'`. I tried to place `align-items justify-content`  at `container` level so in the else, it change element that belongs to `class=second` as well

Comment: so use margin:auto on the box element

Comment: yap...i tried it as well...but it created a scrollbar vertically for some reason

Comment: it will do if your element is bigger than the container which is logical, otherwise you won't get any scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `justify/align` on the parent.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
    <p>it should be center</p>
    <p>it should be center on vertical</p>
  </div>
</div>
```